# F# list of discriminated union sub-types

Tags: f#, discriminated-union, fparsec

I want to present the user with a list of 'FParsec parsers'-plus-'test data' from which they can interactively select and see the results of the parser run on the supplied text.

Specifically, am trying to collect my parser tests in a list of records of this type:

```
type FUNCTION_TEST = 
    | XELEMENT_MATCH of label : string * func : Parser<(int * string), unit> * data : string
    | XKEYVALUE_MATCH of label : string * func : Parser<(string * string), unit> * data : string

let testable_parsers = [( "xElement", xElement, xElement_text3)
                        ( "xKeyValue", xKeyValue, xKeyValue_text)]
```

`xKeyValue` above throws the error...

```
val xKeyValue: Parser<(string * string), unit>

Full name CustomParser.xKeyValue

FS0001:the type '(int * string)' does not match the type 'string * string'
```

I want the user to see and choose a `label` string and see the results of running the parser.

I understand that the parser `xElement : Parser<int * string, unit>` does not match parser `xKeyValue : Parser<(string * string), unit>`.  Both sub-types are part of the `FUNCTION_TEST` discriminated union **BUT** I cannot put the parsers in the same list because their sub-types (`XELEMENT_MATCH` versus `XKEYVALUE_MATCH`) disagree.

I wanted to handle this using a `match ... with` over the discriminated union.

I am new to F# and FParsec and out of elegant ideas.  Do I have to hard-code a menu with `do!` and `printf`s?

How do experienced F# and FParsec developers allow users to select from a menu of options of different types?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit confounded by the `FUNCTION_TEST` type. It looks like you're never using the type or any of its constructors, and if so, why did you define that type in the first place?

After pondering the possible motives you may have had, it looks like perhaps you wanted the `testable_parsers` list to contain values of the `FUNCTION_TEST` type so that you can later match on them?

If that is the case, then what you have is not what you intended: the list that you have constructed contains tuples of three values.

In order to construct values of the `FUNCTION_TEST` type, you need to apply its constructors:

```
testableParsers = [
    XELEMENT_MATCH ("xElement", xElement, xElement_text3)
    XKEYVALUE_MATCH ("xKeyValue", xKeyValue, xKeyValue_text)
]
```

---

But if your only purpose is to present a choice to the user, then I wouldn't even bother with a special type to represent the options. You can just pair labels with *functions* to be called when the user chooses the label:

```
testableParsers = [
    "xElement", fun() -> runParser xElement xElement_text3
    "xKeyValue", fun() -> runParser xKeyValue xKeyValue_text
]
```

This way you don't have to do a `match` on the values of `FUNCTION_TEST` either, just call the function.

Comment: Thank you Fyodor for your answer.

I kept the code fragment short to hopefully save you time.  

Yes, I was trying to `match...with` on the FUNCTION_TEST discriminated union sub-types.  Therefor put all my test-able parsers under that parent type so they could co-exist in one list.  

Am I wrong in believing that F# would do 'duck typing' and automatically construct the `XELEMENT_MATCH` or `XKEYVALUE_MATCH` if F# saw something structured like an `XELEMENT_MATCH`.  

Does F# not automatically construct a structured type when it sees something of that type?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach would be to restructure your data so that you keep all the common things (label and data) in a record, together with a value representing the function - which can then be a discriminated union with a case for each type:

```ml
type Function = 
  | Element of Parser<(int * string), unit>
  | KeyValue of Parser<(string * string), unit>

type Test = 
  { Label : string
    Data : string 
    Function : Function }
```

Now you can create a list of `Test` values, which you can easily iterate over to get all the labels & data:

```ml
let testableParsers = 
  [ { Label = "xElement"; Function = Element(xElement); Data = xElement_text3 }
    { Label = "xKeyValue"; Function = KeyValue(xKeyValue); Datta = xKeyValue_text } ]
```

You will still need to use pattern matching when you want to run a specific `Function`, because this will have to handle the different values you get as a result, but you won't need pattern matching elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tomas.  

Why does F# require I explicitly construct the user-defined types?  Does F# not recognize that `xElement`, which IS of type `Parser<(int * string), unit>`, is the same type as  `XELEMENT_MATCH` and just automatically/implicitly construct the correct user-defined type?  Why not do this when F# does implicitly call the constructor for pre-defined types like `int` and `string`?

Comment: Could F# recognize structures matching user-defined types and implicitly construct them?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're proposing - but I suppose the answer is that F# leads you to a certain way of thinking - where you define the types you need yourself.